# Import multiple excel files and merge into single pandas df with source name as column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge a bunch of xlsx files into a single pandas dataframe in python. Furthermore, I want to include a column that lists the source file for each row. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import glob
import os

# get the path for where the xlsx files are
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']

# create new dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# read data from files and add into dataframe
for f in files_xlsx:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet 1')
    df['Source_file'] = f
    df = df.append(data)
```

however, when I look at the 'Source_file' column it lists the final file it reads as the name for every row. I've spent way more time than I should trying to fix this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your for loop you are writing over each iteration of `df` so you'll only get back the final file,

what you need to do is delcare a list before hand and append do that,

since you called glob lets use that as well.

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd()) + '\*.xlsx')
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Sheet1') for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

#### if you want to add the filename into the df too then,

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd()) + '\*.xlsx')
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Sheet1') for f in files]
file_names = [os.path.basename(f) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs,keys=file_names)
```

#### Using Pathlib module (recommended Python 3.4+)

```
from pathlib import Path
files = [f for f in Path.cwd().glob('*.xlsx')]
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name='Sheet1') for f in files]
file_names = [f.stem for f in files] 
df = pd.concat(dfs,keys=file_names)
```

or as a one liner :

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in Path.cwd().glob('*.xlsx')],keys=[f.stem for f in Path.cwd().glob('*.xlsx')],sort=False)
```